# How to iterate elements over time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout

I'm working on this automated, non-endless slideshow, with dynamically loaded content. Each image has to be acompanied by sound. So far I got dynamic loading of both images and sounds down. But it all happens at once, which it shouldn't. I figured, that `setTimeout` can come in handy here, to set the interval between each pair, but all I got is either last image multiplied by the iteration count or script not working at all. `delay` also didn't prove to be of any help.
Here's whot I got so far:

```
function displayImages(data){   
    var count = data; 
    var pixBox = $('#picture-box'); 
    var imgPre = 'resources/exhibit-'; 
    var imgExt = '.png';
    var sndExt = '.wav';

    for(i = 1; i < count; i++) {        
        var imgSrc = '<img src="' + imgPre + i + imgExt + '">';
        var sndSrc = new Audio(imgPre + i + sndExt);                
        sndSrc.play();
        pixBox.append(imgSrc);
    }   
}
```

My question is: how to set the `setTimeout` (or whatever function is the best here), for it to iterate over time. Say, to set the change of img/sound pairs every 2 seconds?

Comment: You need `setInterval` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout like this:

```
function displayImages(cur, total){   

    var pixBox = $('#picture-box'); 
    var imgPre = 'resources/exhibit-'; 
    var imgExt = '.png';
    var sndExt = '.wav';

    var imgSrc = '<img src="' + imgPre + cur + imgExt + '">';
    var sndSrc = new Audio(imgPre + cur + sndExt);                
    sndSrc.play();
    pixBox.append(imgSrc);

    return setTimeout( 'displayImages(' + ((cur+1)%total) + ',' + total + ')', 2000 );

}
```

And start it off like this: `displayImages(0,total)` where `total` corresponds to your `data` variable.

The reason I like to use `setTimeout` and not `setInterval` in these situations is that `setTimeout` is only called after the previous function has completed. `setInterval` can get back-logged and freeze up your page.

Note that the function returns a handle for the `timeout`. If you should want to stop the animation, you can do this:

```
var animation = displayImages(0,total);
...some code...
clearTimeout(animation);
```

and the animation will stop.

Comment: Still need to get hang of clearTimeout thingie, but that here is what saved my life! Thank you, sir, you're the dude!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setInterval, this does the same code at every interval.

```
var myInterval = window.setInterval(displayImages, 2000);
```

This will make sure your function gets called every 2000 milliseconds.

More information on [MDN setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$(function() {
  var count = 100;
  var i = 0;
  var repeat = setInterval(function() {

    if (i <= count) {
        var imgSrc = '<img src="' + imgPre + i + imgExt + '">';
        var sndSrc = new Audio(imgPre + i + sndExt);                
        sndSrc.play();
        pixBox.append(imgSrc);
        i++;
    }
    else{
        i = 0; //reset count if reaches threshold.
    }

  }, 5000); //5 secs


});
```

With this, if you want to reset the interval on any event you can simple call

```
clearInterval(repeat);
```

Answer (score 0):

See a setInterval example here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/dvygtrs2/1/)

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(fadeDivs, 3000);

function fadeDivs() {
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
    $('#my-img').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(200);
    })
    i++;
}
```